# How can I clone an Object (deep copy) in Dart?

Tags: object, copy, clone, dart

Is there a Language supported way to make a full (deep) copy of an Object in Dart?

If multiple options exist, what are their differences?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

No as far as open issues seems to suggest:

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/3367

And specifically:

> ... Objects have identity, and you can only pass around references to them. There is no implicit copying.

Comment: Thanks, and I did just end writing a clone method myself for the few classes where I need to make a copy (not just a reference). I was spoiled by Ruby - thought this was a standard language feature.

Comment: it's suppose to be a standard language feature =_="

Comment: even in official dart polymer tutorial they implement copyCodelab() function by hand. There really suppose to be such stdlib functionality. I'll file a bug for that.

Comment: how about 6 years later? is this answer still a truth?

Comment: Well this is disappointing. To be fair, many many languages suffer from this issue, even Go has no way to copy an object like you can in C++ or Rust. Anyway [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/35309) is a recent issue I found for this.

Comment: This is the wrong answer. Just because a language has pass-by-reference calls, doesn't mean deep copying is not supported.

Comment: @user48956 Would be great if you can elaborate. The need is a Map of Maps. Say, a complex configuration, The requirement is to be fully clone this, such that it's protected (and maybe even based on need, changed) inside a specific process, but the original object remains unchanged. many languages supports pass-by-ref but also have deep copying out of the box.

Comment: Sure language like scala support deep copies by provided methods to reflect the constructor parameter names, types and values (and you can use them to serialize many classes). Language like python provide reflection methods to find an objects class names and attributes (and use them to perform auto-serialization and deep copying). In 2020, these features from 1990 are what we’ve come to expect in a programmable language.

Comment: Sorry. Lost you at 1990. deepcopy is a convenient method, syntactic sugar. Any one can implement this (some ways for that, from full serialization and deserialization to recursive looping over the object). The question here is, does Dart has this out of the box, The answer is - No. How can this be a wrong answer? Is there a discussion about "is deep copy a good idea", sure. But I don't think it's related.

Comment: Super lame, give-up-the-ship answer.  If nothing else you can loop through each of the objects properties to create a new object.

Comment: This behaviour [comes automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107906/how-can-i-clone-an-object-deep-copy-in-dart/67420251#67420251) with type promotion.

Comment: @dfmiller No, you can't.  The compiler cannot automatically choose which constructor should be invoked for each member, if a constructor is even available.  What would the compiler do if an object has a member with declared with the type of an abstract base class?  Or, if you expect that "looping over each of the object's properties" be done at runtime, then that would require runtime reflection, which would penalize performance and code size.

Comment: how about 10 years later? is this answer still a truth?

Comment: @zionpi Dart does not have copy constructors, so nothing has changed.

Answer (score 60):

Darts built-in collections use a named constructor called "from" to accomplish this. See this post: [Clone a List, Map or Set in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21744480/clone-a-list-map-or-set-in-dart)

```
Map mapA = {
    'foo': 'bar'
};
Map mapB = new Map.from(mapA);
```

Comment: This might work for a simple <String,String> Map, but it will not for more complex maps like <String,Map>. I had the same idea like you, but it didnt work.

Comment: `from` is a constructor. use `new Map.from(mapA);`

Comment: @MosheShaham i don't get it

Comment: @jerinho you are correct that Moshe Shaham's solution does not work for nested maps.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.  As asked, the answer to the question is "There is no general way to create a copy of an arbitrary object in Dart".  There *can* be ways to create copies for *specific types* of objects, but enumerating those would be an overly broad question.

Comment: Additionally, this is an outdated way to copy `Map`s.  Since at least Dart 2, [using `Map.from`/`Set.from`/`List.from` is discouraged](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#dont-use-listfrom-unless-you-intend-to-change-the-type-of-the-result) since they lose type information.  Using `Map.of`/`Set.of`/`List.of` is better, or for `Set`s and `List`s, `.toSet()/`.toList()`.

Comment: Also, I somehow forgot to mention that this does *not* create a deep copy of a `Map`.  It creates a *shallow* copy.

Comment: ideally we don't want to pay the price of (de)serialization just to copy an object.

Comment: This does not answer the question. It is asking about objects not collections of objects.

Answer (score 59):

Late to the party, but I recently faced this problem and had to do something along the lines of :-

```
class RandomObject {

  RandomObject(this.x, this.y);

  RandomObject.clone(RandomObject randomObject): this(randomObject.x, randomObject.y);

  int x;
  int y;
}
```

Then, you can just call copy with the original, like so:

```
final RandomObject original = RandomObject(1, 2);
final RandomObject copy = RandomObject.clone(original);
```

Comment: Hi @Phill I copy/paste your code and it is not working. Can you improve it?

Comment: Hey @pedromassango. It's difficult to improve that code. Send me your code or implementation and I can show you. Something like:- ```var newObject = Random object.clone(oldObject) will return a copied instance.

Comment: It was giving me a error, I just replaced super by this

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted either. It's the closest and cleanest possible way to clone an object without using reflection.

Answer (score 26):

I guess for not-too-complex objects, you could use the convert library:

```
import 'dart:convert';
```

and then use the JSON encode/decode functionality

```
Map clonedObject = JSON.decode(JSON.encode(object));
```

If you're using a custom class as a value in the object to clone, the class either needs to implement a toJson() method or you have to provide a toEncodable function for the JSON.encode method and a reviver method for the decode call.

Comment: it loses type information, and it only works for object types that can be represented by JSON. Most importantly it's *way* slower than it should be.

Comment: It works for me when I customise it into `ClassName.fromJson(jsonDecode(jsonEncode(object)));`. Thanks.

Comment: Great solution, since we have already added JSON support for server communication

Comment: Yes, that works great when you already have `fromJson()` in your models

Answer (score 15):

Unfortunately no language support. What I did is to create an abstract class called `Copyable` which I can implement in the classes I want to be able to copy:

```
abstract class Copyable<T> {
  T copy();
  T copyWith();
}
```

I can then use this as follows, e.g. for a Location object:

```
class Location implements Copyable<Location> {
  Location({
    required this.longitude,
    required this.latitude,
    required this.timestamp,
  });

  final double longitude;
  final double latitude;
  final DateTime timestamp;

  @override
  Location copy() => Location(
        longitude: longitude,
        latitude: latitude,
        timestamp: timestamp,
      );

  @override
  Location copyWith({
    double? longitude,
    double? latitude,
    DateTime? timestamp,
  }) =>
      Location(
        longitude: longitude ?? this.longitude,
        latitude: latitude ?? this.latitude,
        timestamp: timestamp ?? this.timestamp,
      );
}
```

Answer (score 11):

To copy an object without reference, the solution I found was similar to the one posted here, however if the object contains MAP or LIST you have to do it this way:

```
class Item {
  int id;
  String nome;
  String email;
  bool logado;
  Map mapa;
  List lista;
  Item({this.id, this.nome, this.email, this.logado, this.mapa, this.lista});

  Item copyWith({ int id, String nome, String email, bool logado, Map mapa, List lista }) {
    return Item(
      id: id ?? this.id,
      nome: nome ?? this.nome,
      email: email ?? this.email,
      logado: logado ?? this.logado,
      mapa: mapa ?? Map.from(this.mapa ?? {}),
      lista: lista ?? List.from(this.lista ?? []),
    );
  }
}
```

```
Item item1 = Item(
    id: 1,
    nome: 'João Silva',
    email: 'joaosilva@gmail.com',
    logado: true,
    mapa: {
      'chave1': 'valor1',
      'chave2': 'valor2',
    },
    lista: ['1', '2'],
  );

// -----------------
// copy and change data
Item item2 = item1.copyWith(
    id: 2,
    nome: 'Pedro de Nobrega',
    lista: ['4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
  );

// -----------------
// copy and not change data
Item item3 = item1.copyWith();

// -----------------
// copy and change a specific key of Map or List
Item item4 = item1.copyWith();
item4.mapa['chave2'] = 'valor2New';
```

See an example on dartpad

https://dartpad.dev/f114ef18700a41a3aa04a4837c13c70e

Comment: The problem of this solution is when you want to set a null value to variable.

Comment: Really, a suggestion that I can think of now is to set it to null after copying ...:

// ---------------------------------------
Item item2 = item1.copyWith(
    id: 2,
    nome: 'Pedro de Nobrega',
    lista: ['4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
);
item2.email = null;
// ---------------------------------------

Comment: Yeah, but this would not work in a immutable objected, where everything is final.
I have a suggestion:

Item copyWith({ int Function() id, String Function() name .. }) {
    return Item(
      id: id?.call() ?? this.id,
      nome: nome?.call() ?? this.name,
      ...
    );
}

Now you can call:
item.copyWith(name: () => null);

Comment: Excellent. Just using the copyWith() is a good solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

It only works for object types that can be represented by JSON.

```
ClassName newObj = ClassName.fromMap(obj.toMap());
```

or

```
ClassName newObj = ClassName.fromJson(obj.toJson());
```

Comment: In this case, you'll also need to write fromJson() for all the child classes as well which a lot of work to be done.

Comment: Yes, you can use https://stackoverflow.com/a/26616081/1556386 solution too if you don't want to implement fromJson()

Answer (score 7):

With reference to @Phill Wiggins's answer, here is an example with .from constructor and named parameters:

```
class SomeObject{
  String parameter1;
  String parameter2;

  // Normal Constructor
  SomeObject({
    this.parameter1,
    this.parameter2,
  });

  // .from Constructor for copying
  factory SomeObject.from(SomeObject objectA){
    return SomeObject(
      parameter1: objectA.parameter1,
      parameter2: objectA.parameter2,
    );
  }

}
```

Then, do this where you want to copy:

```
SomeObject a = SomeObject(parameter1: "param1", parameter2: "param2");
SomeObject copyOfA = SomeObject.from(a);
```

Comment: This is the simplest and most straightforward approach. I tried several measures and they are all too complicated and not worth it.

Comment: This solution works very well. Beware that making a copy from a function within the class will still return the reference. The copy has to be made in another class in order to work.

Answer (score 6):

Let's say you a have class

```
Class DailyInfo

  { 
     String xxx;
  }
```

Make a new clone of the class object dailyInfo by

```
 DailyInfo newDailyInfo =  new DailyInfo.fromJson(dailyInfo.toJson());
```

For this to work your class must have implemented

```
 factory DailyInfo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$DailyInfoFromJson(json);


Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$DailyInfoToJson(this);
```

which can be done by making class serializable using

```
@JsonSerializable(fieldRename: FieldRename.snake, includeIfNull: false)
Class DailyInfo{ 
 String xxx;
}
```

Comment: Cloning using JSON is no good idea. It limits the objects you can clone & reduces performance.

Comment: this also doesn't work well if the object has a contains a list of other serializable objects. For example Order has a list of products... even if products are serializable you will see an issue when there's a product in the order.

Answer (score 5):

There's no API for cloning/deep-copying built into Dart.

We have to [write `clone()` methods ourselves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51356837/2301224) & (for better or worse) the Dart authors want it that way.

#### Deep copy Object /w List

If the Object we're cloning has a `List` of Objects as a field, we need to `List.generate` that field and those Objects need their own clone method.

Example of cloning method (`copyWith()`) on an `Order` class with a `List` field of objects (and those nested objects also have a `copyWith()`):

```
  Order copyWith({
    int? id,
    Customer? customer,
    List<OrderItem>? items,
  }) {
    return Order(
      id: id ?? this.id,
      customer: customer ?? this.customer,
      //items: items ?? this.items, // this will NOT work, it references 
      items: items ?? List.generate(this.items.length, (i) => this.items[i].copyWith()),
    );
  }
```

Gunter mentions this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50460378/2301224).

Note, we **cannot** use `List.from(items)` nor `[...items]`.  These both only make [shallow copies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21744481/2301224).

Comment: Don't we need to use also `customer: customer ?? this.customer.copyWith()`?

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Addittionally u should extend your class from Equatable...this is how I work with the BLoC pattern and I have no problems

Answer (score 5):

Dart does not share Memory within multiple threads (isolate), so...

```
extension Clone<T> on T {
  
  /// in Flutter
  Future<T> clone() => compute<T, T>((e) => e, this);

  /// in Dart
  Future<T> clone() async {
    final receive = ReceivePort();
    receive.sendPort.send(this);
    return receive.first.then((e) => e as T).whenComplete(receive.close);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Trying using a [Copyable](https://pub.dev/documentation/copyable/latest/index.html#usage) interface provided by Dart.

Comment: seems good but the owner doesnt seem to maintain the repo. I dont suggest using random 3rd party packages like this.

Comment: I personally prefer the [copy_with_extension_gen 1.4.0](https://pub.dev/packages/copy_with_extension_gen) package, it basically does the same thing but gives you more control and is being maintained

Answer (score 4):

there is an easier way for this issue
just use `...` operator
for example, clone a Map

```
Map p = {'name' : 'parsa','age' : 27};
Map n = {...p};
```

also, you can do this for class properties.
in my case, I was needed to clone a listed property of a class.
So:

```
class P1 {
List<String> names = [some data];
}

/// codes
P1 p = P1();
List<String> clonedList = [...p.names]
// now clonedList is an unreferenced type
```

Comment: This will copy the `Map` itself, but it will not perform a deep copy of the `Map`s keys and values. (`Map` keys should be immutable objects, though.)

Comment: yes, unfortunately, I think this is one of the dart language weaknesses.
it hasn't a safe way to simple or deep clone, especially for classes

Comment: This works for me when i combine it with equatable to do comparisons

Answer (score 4):

This works for me.

Use the fromJson and toJson from your Object's Class on JSON serializing

```
var copy = ObjectClass.fromJson(OrigObject.toJson());
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in way of deep cloning an object - you have to provide the method for it yourself.

I often have a need to encode/decode my classes from JSON, so I usually provide `MyClass fromMap(Map)` and `Map<String, dynamic> toJson()` methods. These can be used to create a deep clone by first encoding the object to JSON and then decoding it back.

However, for performance reasons, I usually implement a separate `clone` method instead. It's a few minutes work, but I find that it is often time well spent.

In the example below, `cloneSlow` uses the JSON-technique, and `cloneFast` uses the explicitly implemented clone method. The printouts prove that the clone is really a deep clone, and not just a copy of the reference to `a`.

```
import 'dart:convert';

class A{
  String a;
  A(this.a);
  
  factory A.fromMap(Map map){
    return A(
        map['a']
   );
  }
  
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson(){
    return {
      'a': a
    };
  }
  
  
  A cloneSlow(){
    return A.fromMap(jsonDecode(jsonEncode(this)));
  }

  A cloneFast(){
    return A(
      a
    );
  }
  
  
  @override
  String toString() => 'A(a: $a)';
}

void main() {
  A a = A('a');
  A b = a.cloneFast();
  b.a = 'b';
  
  print('a: $a   b: $b');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An example of Deep copy in dart.

```
void main() {
  Person person1 = Person(
      id: 1001,
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: 'Doe',
      email: 'john.doe@email.com',
      alive: true);

  Person person2 = Person(
      id: person1.id,
      firstName: person1.firstName,
      lastName: person1.lastName,
      email: person1.email,
      alive: person1.alive);

  print('Object: person1');
  print('id     : ${person1.id}');
  print('fName  : ${person1.firstName}');
  print('lName  : ${person1.lastName}');
  print('email  : ${person1.email}');
  print('alive  : ${person1.alive}');
  print('=hashCode=: ${person1.hashCode}');

  print('Object: person2');
  print('id     : ${person2.id}');
  print('fName  : ${person2.firstName}');
  print('lName  : ${person2.lastName}');
  print('email  : ${person2.email}');
  print('alive  : ${person2.alive}');
  print('=hashCode=: ${person2.hashCode}');
}

class Person {
  int id;
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  String email;
  bool alive;
  Person({this.id, this.firstName, this.lastName, this.email, this.alive});
}
```

And the output below.

```
id     : 1001
fName  : John
lName  : Doe
email  : john.doe@email.com
alive  : true
=hashCode=: 515186678

Object: person2
id     : 1001
fName  : John
lName  : Doe
email  : john.doe@email.com
alive  : true
=hashCode=: 686393765
```

Answer (score 1):

// Hope this work

```
 void main() {
  List newList = [{"top": 179.399, "left": 384.5, "bottom": 362.6, "right": 1534.5}, {"top": 384.4, "left": 656.5, "bottom": 574.6, "right": 1264.5}];
  List tempList = cloneMyList(newList);
  tempList[0]["top"] = 100;
  newList[1]["left"] = 300;
  print(newList);
  print(tempList);
}

List cloneMyList(List originalList) {
 List clonedList = new List();
  for(Map data in originalList) {
    clonedList.add(Map.from(data));
  }
  return clonedList;
}
```

Comment: This works thanks. Been struggling all day with a bug due to shallow cloning because I always thought `Map.from` always deep copies and I had been using that.

Answer (score 1):

You can get help from the **compute** function ** Not Recommended ** though.

```
final clonedData = await compute((dynamic data) => return data));
```

Answer (score 0):

make a helper class:

```
class DeepCopy {
  static clone(obj) {
    var tempObj = {};
    for (var key in obj.keys) {
      tempObj[key] = obj[key];
    }
    return tempObj;
  }
}
```

and copy what you want:

```
 List cloneList = [];
 if (existList.length > 0) {
    for (var element in existList) {
        cloneList.add(DeepCopy.clone(element));
    }
 }
```

Comment: It does not work. Here is the exception on my custom model.

Class 'Scenario' has no instance getter 'keys'.
Receiver: Instance of 'Scenario'
Tried calling: keys

Answer (score 0):

Let's say, you want to deep copy an object `Person` which has an attribute that is a list of other objects `Skills`. By convention, we use the `copyWith` method with optional parameters for deep copy, but you can name it anything you want.

You can do something like this

```dart
class Skills {
  final String name;

  Skills({required this.name});

  Skills copyWith({
    String? name,
  }) {
    return Skills(
      name: name ?? this.name,
    );
  }
}

class Person {
  final List<Skills> skills;

  const Person({required this.skills});

  Person copyWith({
    List<Skills>? skills,
  }) =>
      Person(skills: skills ?? this.skills.map((e) => e.copyWith()).toList());
}
```

Keep in mind that using only `this.skills` will only copy the reference of the list. So original object and the copied object will point to the same list of skills.

```dart
  Person copyWith({
    List<Skills>? skills,
  }) =>
      Person(skills: skills ?? this.skills);
```

If your list is primitive type you can do it like this. Primitive types are automatically copied so you can use this shorter syntax.

```
class Person {
  final List<int> names;

  const Person({required this.names});

  Person copyWith({
    List<int>? names,
  }) =>
      Person(names: names ?? []...addAll(names));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer doesn't provide an answer, and the highest-rated answer 'doesn't work' for more complex Map types.

***It also doesn't make a deep copy, it makes a shallow copy which seems to be how most people land on this page. My solution also makes a shallow copy.***

JSON-cloning, which a few people suggest, just seems like gross overhead for a shallow-clone.

I had this basically

```
List <Map<String, dynamic>> source = [{'sampledata', []}];
List <Map<String, dynamic>> destination = [];
```

This worked, but of course, it's not a clone, it's just a reference, but it proved in my real code that the data types of `source` and `destination` were compatible (identical in my case, and this case).

```
destination[0] = source[0];
```

This did not work

```
destination[0] = Map.from(source[0]);
```

This is the easy solution

```
destionation[0] = Map<String, dynamic>.from(source[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Kotlin-style copy method could be implemented with the implementation of the prototype pattern as

```
class LoginState{
  String userName = "";
  String password = "";

  LoginState copy({String? userName, String? password}){
    var loginState = LoginState();
    loginState.userName = this.userName;
    loginState.password = this.password;
    if(userName != null) {
      loginState.userName = userName;
    }
    if(password != null){
      loginState.password = password;
    }
    return loginState;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

My Solution:

```
import 'dart:convert';
Map newMap = json.decode(json.encode(oldMap));
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).