# Is there any dart equivalent for jquery extend?

Tags: jquery, dart

I want to merge two Maps. I can use Map.addAll method, but this method does not support deep merge. I want to use addAll for all Maps and equvivalent method for Lists inside. Recursive solution is not simple task for me and using JS iterop is dirty. Any solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I clone an Object (deep copy) in Dart?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107906/how-can-i-clone-an-object-deep-copy-in-dart)

Comment: Why not copy $.extend from the source?

Comment: @megawac not a duplicate, that question is asking for a language built in way and the answer is simply 'no'.

Comment: And it is for merging maps which is different form deep copying of objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have ported it for the [Angular Dart UI](https://github.com/akserg/angular.dart.ui) project, but it's not yet properly tested (but in used in the Rating component)

https://github.com/akserg/angular.dart.ui/blob/master/lib/helper/extend.dart

will be moved shortly to

https://github.com/akserg/angular.dart.ui/blob/master/lib/utils/extend.dart

Comment: Thx, good work. I've started to work on my own solution with strong typing and not breaking pointers to target, if possible. This work is a great inspiration.