# Clone a List, Map or Set in Dart

Tags: collections, dart, clone

Coming from a Java background: what is the recommended way to "clone" a Dart `List`, `Map` and `Set`?

Comment: I was going to add my own answer here but instead I turned it into an article: [Cloning lists, maps, and sets in Dart](https://suragch.medium.com/cloning-lists-maps-and-sets-in-dart-d0fc3d6a570a?sk=d524c3b1aa8d3565c2149991cc7a2072)

Answer (score 177, accepted):

Use of `clone()` in Java is tricky and questionable<sup>1,2</sup>. Effectively, `clone()` is a copy constructor and for that, the Dart `List`, `Map` and `Set` types each have a [named constructor](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch02.html#ch02-constructors-named) named `.from()` that perform a [shallow copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy); e.g. given these declarations

```dart
  Map<String, int> numMoons, moreMoons;
  numMoons = const <String,int>{ 'Mars' : 2, 'Jupiter' : 27 };
  List<String> planets, morePlanets;
```

you can use `.from()` like this:

```dart
  moreMoons = new Map<String,int>.from(numMoons)
    ..addAll({'Saturn' : 53 });
  planets = new List<String>.from(numMoons.keys);
  morePlanets = new List<String>.from(planets)
    ..add('Pluto');
```

Note that `List.from()` more generally accepts an iterator rather than just a `List`.

For sake of completeness, I should mention that the `dart:html` `Node` class defines a [clone()](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/#dart-dom-html.Node@id_clone) method.

---

<sup>1</sup> J. Bloch, "*Effective Java*" 2nd Ed., Item 11.
<sup>2</sup> [B. Venners, "*Josh Bloch on Design: Copy Constructor versus Cloning*", 2002](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html). Referenced from here<sup>3</sup>. Quote from the article:

> > *If you've read the item about cloning in my book, especially if you read between the lines, you will know that I think clone is deeply broken. ---J.Bloch*

<sup>3</sup> [Dart Issue #6459, clone instance(object)](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=6459).

Comment: Josh Bloch was actually involved in some of the early design of the Dart collections API. [Old interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wmsVHdllIPM).

Comment: The .from() and .addAll() not really make a clone. They add a reference in the new Map/List/Set. For example:   Map map1 = {
              'one': {'name': 1},
              'two': {'name': 2},
              'three': [{
                'a': {
                  'A': 1,
                  'B': 2
                },
                'b': {
                  'A': 3,
                  'B': 4
                }
              }]
  };

  Map map2 = new Map.from(map1);
  map2['two']['name'] = 4;

After changing map2['two']['name'], map1 changed as well

Comment: Right. `.from()` is a _shallow_ copy constructor. Just to be clear, I never said that `.from()` performed a clone operation. What I wrote was the `clone()` was a kind of copy constructor.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you know the type of the original `List`, `List<E>.of()` might be better.

Answer (score 141):

With the new version of dart cloning of a Map or List become quite easy.
You can try this method for making a deep clone of List and Map.

For List

```
List a = ['x','y', 'z'];
List b = [...a];
```

For Maps

```
Map mapA = {"a":"b"};
Map mapB = {...mapA};
```

For Sets

```
Set setA = {1,2,3,};
Set setB = {...setA};
```

I hope someone find this helpful.

Comment: @funder7 
Yes, this works with Set also.
 
Set set1 = {1,2,3,};
Set s = {...set1};

Comment: But I've tried to use it and I've got an error: {...set1} was returning a list! I did something wrong? Or maybe it's a beta feature? I'm using the stable channel

Comment: @funder7
It worked fine when i run the same same code in dartpad.
see here
https://imgur.com/JQkWZJS

Comment: This will not clone a list of objects! The list will contain references to each object. https://dartpad.dartlang.org/?41547dfffef02aeb34e14c1123adf72a

Comment: Wrong ! copy only non-object data . see above

Comment: Yes it is just a swallow copy. The references of each object item will be same.

Comment: Set setA = {obj1,  obj2,  obj3};
Set setB = {...setA};  ==> this is same and not a clone

Answer (score 46):

If you are using dart > 2.3.0, You can use spread operator something like:

```
List<int> a = [1,2,3];
List<int> b = [...a]; // copy of a
```

Comment: Note that this will not clone a list of objects. The list will contain references.

Comment: this is a shallow copy

Comment: Unfortunately it will return a List, so it's not usable with Sets either

Comment: @funder It's a `List` because of the square brackets.  The general technique works with `Set`s or `Map`s: `{...set}` or `{...map}`.

Answer (score 37):

For lists and sets, I typically use

```
List<String> clone = []..addAll(originalList);
```

The caveat, as @kzhdev mentions, is that `addAll()` and `from()`

> [Do] not really make a clone. They add a reference in the new Map/List/Set.

That's usually ok with me, but I would keep it in mind.

Answer (score 26):

For deep copy (clone), you can use :

```
Map<String, dynamic> src = {'a': 123, 'b': 456};
Map<String, dynamic> copy = json.decode(json.encode(src));
```

but there may be some concerns about the performance.

Comment: I don't completely understand why this reply was downvoted as it really has some advantage. Yes, there will be some performance issues but it will really make COPIES of lists inside, not just copying a link to them. So I'll you an upvote

Comment: Your answer will work only if there are only primitive attributes. Imagine that you have getters/setters/functions. json.decode->encode will break this all, dude

Comment: @qiAlex that is obvious, but it is a way that someone can choose, dude. Many times when you want to clone and object that is the case that it contain primitives. What does is mean to clone a function!

Comment: @qiAlex Just add `fromJson` to your source class, then for a list of objects: `final copy = List<SrcClass>.from(json.decode(json.encode(src)).map((e) => SrcClass.fromJson(e)).toList()`.

Answer (score 16):

Method-1: Recommended

**For cloning a multi-dimensional (nested) List or Map**, use the
json.decode() and json.encode()

```
List newList = json.decode(json.encode(oldList));
Map newMap = json.decode(json.encode(oldList));
```

Method-2:

```
List newList = [...oldList];
Map newMap = {...oldMap}
```

Method-3:

```
List newList = List.from(oldList);
Map newMap = Map.from(oldMap);
```

Method-4:

```
List newList = List.of(oldList);
Map newMap = Map.of(oldMap);
```

Method-5:

```
List newList = List.unmodifiable(oldList);
Map newMap = Map.unmodifiable(oldMap);
```

For more References:

https://www.kindacode.com/article/how-to-clone-a-list-or-map-in-dart-and-flutter/
https://coflutter.com/dart-flutter-how-to-clone-copy-a-list/

Answer (score 10):

This solution should work:

```dart
  List list1 = [1,2,3,4]; 

  List list2 = list1.map((element)=>element).toList();
```

It's for a list but should work the same for a map etc, remember to add to list if its a list at the end

Comment: Ah, thanks, so we can do this `list1.map((element)=>element.copy()).toList();` if our classes have a `copy` method defined and now get a truly deep copy.

Answer (score 8):

**Map.from()** only works for 1D map.

To **copy multi dimensional map without reference** in dart use following method

```dart
    Map<keyType, valueType> copyDeepMap( Map<keyType, valueType> map )
    {
        Map<keyType, valueType> newMap = {};

        map.forEach
        (
            (key, value)
            {
                newMap[key] =( value is Map ) ? copyDeepMap(value) : value ;
            }
        );

        return newMap;
    }
```

Comment: While this works, it does not keep the type information of nested maps. It seems it's not possible to do that, except for maybe using reflection...

Answer (score 4):

Best solution for me:

```
List temp = {1,2,3,4}
List platforms = json.decode(json.encode(parent.platforms));
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you use DateTime in the list/map/set that you're copying.

Answer (score 4):

This was my solution. I hope it can help someone.

```
  factory Product.deepCopy(Product productToCopy) => new Product(
    productToCopy.id,
    productToCopy.title,
    productToCopy.description,
    productToCopy.price,
    productToCopy.imageUrl,
    productToCopy.isFavorite,
  );}
```

Answer (score 2):

To copy Map<String, List> filtered;

```
 var filteredNewCopy = filtered.map((key, value) => MapEntry(key, [...value]));
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no 100% bullet proof way of making an exact isolated copy, but the [answer from Manish Dhruw](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60089872/930640) is pretty good. However, it will only work for Maps containing simple variable types and nested Maps.

To extend it to also work with other common collections, such as `List` and `Set`, and **combinations of them**, you could use something like the code below.

You don't really need the `DeepCopyable` class, but it would be useful if you want to easily make your own classes "deep-copyable" with these functions.

```
abstract class DeepCopyable{
  T deepCopy<T>();
}

List<T> listDeepCopy<T>(List list){
  List<T> newList = List<T>();

  list.forEach((value) {
    newList.add(
      value is Map ? mapDeepCopy(value) :
      value is List ? listDeepCopy(value) :
      value is Set ? setDeepCopy(value) :
      value is DeepCopyable ? value.deepCopy() :
      value
    );
  });

  return newList;
}

Set<T> setDeepCopy<T>(Set s){
  Set<T> newSet = Set<T>();

  s.forEach((value) {
    newSet.add(
      value is Map ? mapDeepCopy(value) :
      value is List ? listDeepCopy(value) :
      value is Set ? setDeepCopy(value) :
      value is DeepCopyable ? value.deepCopy() :
      value
    );
  });

  return newSet;
}


Map<K,V> mapDeepCopy<K,V>(Map<K,V> map){
  Map<K,V> newMap = Map<K,V>();

  map.forEach((key, value){
    newMap[key] =
      value is Map ? mapDeepCopy(value) :
      value is List ? listDeepCopy(value) :
      value is Set ? setDeepCopy(value) :
      value is DeepCopyable ? value.deepCopy() :
      value;
  });

  return newMap;
}
```

As I mentioned, it's obviously still not 100% bullet proof - for example you will loose type information for nested collections.

Answer (score 0):

```dart
List<int> a = [1,2,3];
List<int> b = a.toList(); // copy of a
```

Seems to work too

**Dart 2.15

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution,hope it works for you

```
class Person {
  String? name;
  int? age;
  Person(this.name, this.age);
  factory Person.clone(Person source) {
    return Person(source.name, source.age);
  }
}

final personList = [
  Person('Tom', 22),
  Person('Jane', 25),
];
final yourCopy = personList.map((p) => Person.clone(p)).toList();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with dynamic typed data (aka sourced from JSON or built to encode as JSON) you can use this function to perform a deep copy:

```dart
cloneDeep(value) {
  if (value is List<dynamic>) {
    return value.map<dynamic>(
      (item) => cloneDeep(item),
    ).toList();
  } else if (value is Map) {
    return value.map<String, dynamic>(
        (key, item) => MapEntry<String, dynamic>(key, cloneDeep(item)));
  }
  return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

best solution is use of `toMap()` and `fromMap()` for classes.

```
class A {
   String title;

   A(Map<String, Object> map){  // fromMap() or fromJson()
    title= map['title'];
  }

   Map<String, Object> toMap(){
    final res = <String, Object>{};
    res['title'] = title;

    return res;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The given answer is good, but be aware of the `generate` constructor which is helpful if you want to "grow" a fixed length list, e.g.:

```
List<String> list = new List<String>(5);
int depth = 0; // a variable to track what index we're using

...
depth++;
if (list.length <= depth) {
  list = new List<String>.generate(depth * 2,
      (int index) => index < depth ? list[index] : null,
      growable: false);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

final list = [[],[]];
final cloned = list.copyRange(0, list.length-1);