# how do i create a copy of List<T> in dart when T is object see below code

Tags: dart, flutter

in https://dartpad.dartlang.org/ editor I typed below to test my issue.

based on my testing apparently list.from function only create a NEW copy when the T is not object/class

I tested list.from for List it works like charm but not class/object.

please let me know how to create a new copy of the list of T below code so that when we change the list in one place, the other place does not get change.

thanks

```
void main() {
  List<Status> statuses = <Status>[
    Status(name: 'Confirmed', isCheck: true),
    Status(name: 'Cancelled', isCheck: true),
  ];
  print('statuses = ${statuses.toList().map((x) => x.name + '=' + x.isCheck.toString())}');

  //this supposed to create a new list of T but apparently only work for non-object
  List<Status> otherStatuses =  new List<Status>.from(statuses);

  print('otherStatuses= ${otherStatuses.toList().map((x) => x.name + '=' + x.isCheck.toString())}');

 otherStatuses.singleWhere((x)=>x.name=='Cancelled').isCheck=false;

  print('after the changes only on otherStatuses');
  print('statuses = ${statuses.toList().map((x) => x.name + '=' + x.isCheck.toString())}');

  print('statuses2 = ${otherStatuses.toList().map((x) => x.name + '=' + x.isCheck.toString())}');

  print('why the original status (cancelled) equal to false?');

}


class Status {
  String name;
  bool isCheck;

  Status({
    this.name,
    this.isCheck,
  });
}
```

Comment: You are getting a new copy of the _list_, you aren't getting a new copy of the objects _within_ the list. There is no general way to implement a deep collection copy, you must implement the copy for the elements within the list yourself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To create a list of new elements use the `map()` function you already used for other purpose in your code:

```
List<Status> otherStatuses = statuses.map((status)=>Status(name:status.name, isCheck:status.isCheck)).toList()
```

Comment: I think this answer is workaround kind of but it works, what if the T has so many properties, is there a better way to solve this? because of course, I have simplified the properties in a real application is more complex than this.

Comment: @Hendra well, I would not use the term "workaround". I would use this term for something that is expected to work in a way but it doesn't. Here you are using the [`List.from()`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/List/List.from.html) methods that builds a list from the elements of the iteratrable passed and these elements are passed by reference so they end up to be the same objects. You need to forge a brand new element from the element passed. Where you decide to do it (in the map function, on a top level function or in a instance clone method) that it's up to you.

Comment: This doesn't work. It shouldn't have a green check.

Comment: @EliWhittle why do you say that? Here's a [gist](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/3e95a5d076d07f3c1ed8d70cab34127c) proving it works.

Answer (score 0):

There are different threads about the same [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21744480/clone-a-list-map-or-set-in-dart) find multiple solutions. In the [dart repository](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/3367) they had a discussion about a clone function as well and decided not to implement it and they a [issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/35309) for it.

Comment: Sorry maybe I've edited to much, but still your solution with `new  List<Status>.from(statuses)` doesn't work. If you make final fields, than you cannot change them, I think I'm missing something...

Comment: You are right, it needs some more changes, i added them to the original post

Answer (score 0):

you can also use

```
List<Status> otherStatuses = List<Status>.generate(statuses.length,(i) => Status(name: statuses[i].name , isCheck:statuses[i].isCheck));
```

**regarding WHY?**

Your code did not work simply because the new `otherStatuses` list was referencing the same `Status`(s) object(s) So when you was changing it, it also change in the original `statuses` list because it is the *same object*.