# dart how to assign list into a new list variable

Tags: dart

I am trying to extend a list just by using `add` method like this

```
List<String> mylists = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var d = mylists.add('d');
print(d);
```

It gives error 
`This expression has type 'void' and can't be used.
  print(d);`

Why i cannot save the list in a new variable? Thank you

Comment: You are trying to assign the result of add to a new variable. `add()` alters the existing list. You could just reassign `mylists` to `d` but this would create a reference. If you want a copy(aka keep the old one) look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21744480/clone-a-list-map-or-set-in-dart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refering Dart docs: https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/List-class.html

The `add` method of `List` class has return type of `void`.
So you were unable to assign `var d`.
To save list in new variable use:

```
List<String> mylists = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
mylists.add('d');
var d = mylists;
print(d);
```

**First add the new String i.e. 'd'**
**And then assign it to new variable**

Answer (score 5):

`mylists.add('d')` will add the argument to the original list.

If you want to create a new list you have several possibilities:

```
List<String> mylists = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

// with the constructor
var l1 = List.from(mylists);
l1.add('d');

// with .toList()
var l2 = mylists.toList();
l2.add('d');

// with cascade as one liner
var l3 = List.from(mylists)..add('d');
var l4 = mylists.toList()..add('d');

// in a upcoming version of dart with spread (not yet available)
var l5 = [...myList, 'd'];
```