# All shuffled list are same in flutter

Tags: flutter, list, shuffle

```
List<HotAndNEwData> result = response.results;
    List<HotAndNEwData> pastYear = result;
    pastYear.shuffle();
    List<HotAndNEwData> trending = result;
    trending.shuffle();
    List<HotAndNEwData> southIndian = result;
    southIndian.shuffle();
    List<HotAndNEwData> dramas = result;
    dramas.shuffle();
```

I need to get 4 different lists, but at end of this code I get the same list in all variables, please suggest a solution for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the same list in all variables because it does not do a copy but only creates a refereces.

You have to make a copy of the list. I believe this should help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/21744481/3146225

So it would look something like this:

```
List<HotAndNEwData> pastYear = List.of(result);
pastYear.shuffle();
List<HotAndNEwData> trending = List.of(result);
trending.shuffle();
List<HotAndNEwData> southIndian = List.of(result);
southIndian.shuffle();
List<HotAndNEwData> dramas = List.of(result);
dramas.shuffle();
```

Comment: thanks bro...  

like this also working...

        List<HotAndNEwData> result = response.results;
        List<HotAndNEwData> pastYear =result.toList();
        pastYear.shuffle();
        List<HotAndNEwData> trending = result.toList();
        trending.shuffle();
        List<HotAndNEwData> southIndian = result.toList();
        southIndian.shuffle();
        List<HotAndNEwData> dramas = result.toList();
        dramas.shuffle();