# in dart, which is better List.generate or List.of or List.from

Tags: list, dart

[in Dart Documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.1/dart-core/List-class.html) we have three iterable options to choose from to create lists .which one is best suited for what purpose and which is more effiecient for what purpose?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Dart, what's the difference between List.from and .of, and between Map.from and .of?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50320220/in-dart-whats-the-difference-between-list-from-and-of-and-between-map-from-a) `List.generate` is quite different from either `List.of`/`List.from`; it's used to construct a `List` from dynamically generated elements, not to copy an existing `Iterable`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Basically, you should never use any of those constructors.

Each has its use, but most of those uses can be written using list literals now.

The `List.generate` is a counterpart to `List.filled`. The latter creates a list filled with the same value in each slot, the former allows you to compute a new value for each slot.
With collection-for, I'd probably write:

```dart
 var newList = [for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) compute(i)];
```

instead of

```dart
 var newList = List.generate(10, compute);
```

(even more so if I can inline the `compute` function).
The one case where `generate` makes sense is to create a fixed-length list. The literal cannot do that.

I'd also say that you should *never* use `List.of(something)`.
Use `something.toList()` or `[...something]` instead. If you need to up-cast, say create a `List<num>` from an `Iterable<int>`, you can do `<num>[...something]`, but you can't use `toList`. If you need to make a *fixed-length* `List<num>`, ... then I think `List<num>.of(something, growable: false)` is actually the simplest solution.

The only reason to use `List.from` is when the original iterable does not have as tight a type as needed. If you know that your `Iterable<num>` contains only integers, you might want to do `List<int>.from(iterable)`. You can also do `iterable.cast<int>().toList()` or `[for (var v in iterable) v as int]`, but `List.from` can be shorter. *Always* provide a type variable to `List.from`.

So, in general: Only use one of these constructors if you need a fixed-length list (passing `growable: false`), or if you want to down-cast the elements using `List.from`, and then always provide the type argument.

Otherwise use list literals. That's probably going to be more efficient too because it avoids some function calls.

Comment: As an update, `List.generate` would now be the fastest approach for null-safe list generation, starting from Dart 2.9. https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/42283#issuecomment-646167104

Comment: I think you told me the meaning of "pendant" in one of your other answers to me, but I can't find it now. What is it that you mean by *"`List.generate` is a pendant to `List.filled`"*?

Comment: Since you can also create a fixed-length list with `something.toList(growable: false)`, is there still any need to use something like `List<num>.of(something, growable: false)`? Or are they equivalent?

Comment: If you wish to create a `List<num>` from a `List<int>` (in order to add further doubles to the list later), then you need to use `List<num>.from(intList)`. The `intList.toList()` can only create a new `List<int>`. Otherwise the two are basically equivalent. The `.toList()` has a chance to be slightly more efficient since it knows (or can know) the implementation of the list it works on, where as `List.of` just knows it's some `Iterable`, and it has some overhead just from trying to detect cases where it can be more efficient (like checking whether `length` is efficient).

Comment: `List.toList(...)` implementation uses `List.of()` constructor, may I know where that efficiency comes from?

Comment: There is no `List.toList` method implementation because `List` is an abstract interface. The `ListBase`/`ListMixin` implementations cannot assume anything except the object being a list. Other `List` implementations can *potentially* know more about themselves. In practice, few needs to because lists are such wonderfully simple data structures. If Dart had something more complicated, say like Java's [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), that would probably be able to take advantage of a more specialized `toList` implementation.

Comment: I think I couldn't frame my sentence clearly. I know that there's no implementation of `toList` in `List`, I was talking about [this toList](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.4/dart-core/Iterable/toList.html). So, the question was if `Iterable.toList` is actually invoking `List.of`, then why don't we directly use `List.of(...)`, why there would be a performance difference?

Answer (score 2):

List.generate - This is useful if the source of your list is either not of type List or if you need a special logic when you retrieve list elements;

List.of - Type checking is done at compile time.

List.from - Type checking is only done during runtime.

Both List.of and List.from work the same. But you should prefer List.of over List.from to ensure type checking is performed as early as compile time.

If you want to look more closely, take a look at this example: https://dartpad.dev/b9cd4acdeec266cb366155c6ec40b4f1