# Non-mutating sorted list in Dart

Tags: sorting, dart, collections

I can sort a list like this in Dart:

```dart
final myList = [6, 3, 7, 1, 0, 2];
myList.sort();
```

However, this is a destructive sort since it mutates it in place. I'd like to do something like this:

```dart
final myList = [6, 3, 7, 1, 0, 2];
final newList = myList.sorted();
```

where my list stays the same but `newList` contains the sorted list. Dart apparently doesn't have this functionality, so how do I implement that myself?

In searching for the answer to this question my main struggle was knowing the proper way to copy a list, which wasn't as obvious as it seems like it should be. [I found the answer to that](https://suragch.medium.com/cloning-lists-maps-and-sets-in-dart-d0fc3d6a570a), so I am also posting an answer to my original question below, Q&A style.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a new sorted list without affecting the original list like so:

```dart
final myList = [6, 3, 7, 1, 0, 2];
final sorted = myList.toList()..sort();
```

Calling `toList()` copies the list. The `..` is to get a reference to the list itself since `sort()` is a void function. This gives the same result:

```dart
final sorted = myList.toList();
sorted.sort();
```

Printing the values of both lists gives the following results:

```dart
print(myList); // [6, 3, 7, 1, 0, 2]
print(sorted); // [0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7]
```

You can read more about copying lists [here](https://suragch.medium.com/cloning-lists-maps-and-sets-in-dart-d0fc3d6a570a).

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to create a fixed-length list.

```dart
final myList = [6, 3, 7, 1, 0, 2];
final sortedList = myList.toList(growable: false)..sort();
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that this question is really "How can I copy a `List`?", since you can trivially perform a mutating sort on the copy afterward.

There are multiple ways to copy an `Iterable` to a new `List`:

- Using a method on the original `Iterable`: `iterable.toList()`
- Using a `List` constructor: `List.of(iterable)`
- Using the spread operator in a `List` literal: `[...iterable]`. Note that this always creates a growable `List`.

Note that `List.from` should not be used since that uses `dynamic` types and loses type information.  [Effective Dart prefers `.toList()`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#dont-use-listfrom-unless-you-intend-to-change-the-type-of-the-result).

Also note that the above applies to `Set`s too (`iterable.toSet()`, `{...iterable}`, `Set.of(iterable)`).

Comment: My understanding is that `List.of` isn't useful for anything (since `toList` can also specify non-growable). `List.from` is useful for downcasting but the type should be specified. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61536959/in-dart-which-is-better-list-generate-or-list-of-or-list-from/61541310#61541310

Comment: @Suragch Right, `List.of` isn't any better than `.toList()`.  I *do* contend that `List.of` can be more readable than `.toList`; it's more obvious that `List.of` creates a copy, and the code might want to emphasize that.

Comment: I also didn't mean to imply that `List.of` should necessarily be the preferred approach, only that `List.from` should be avoided.  I'll adjust the wording.

Comment: I agree with you that `List.of` is more readable than `toList`. It seems very strange indeed to call `toList` when you already have a list. I will say, though, that the mere existence of `List.from` blurred the meaning of `List.of` quite a bit for me at first.

Comment: @jamesdlin As`List.of` is more readable than `.toList()`, I think Dart team should change `List.of` implementation to actually return `.toList()` because the current implementation of `List.of` seems to carry no meaning.