# What is the most effective way to replace an item in a list?

Tags: flutter, dart

Let's say we have a class:

```dart
class BasicDto {
  const BasicDto(this.id);
  final int id;
}
```

And a immutable list:

```dart
  final values = const [
    BasicDto(1),
    BasicDto(2),
    BasicDto(3),
  ];
```

Now we want to get a copy of the list with updated value.
My current approach is:

```dart
List<BasicDto> replace(BasicDto dto, List<BasicDto> list) {
  final index = list.indexWhere((item) => item.id == dto.id);
  if (index != -1) {
    return list.toList()..[index] = dto;
  }
  return list;
}
```

Is there any way to do it more elegant (effective) in terms of readability, speed and brevity ?

Comment: how long is it? just 3 or 33 or 333 items? if so it does not really mater how you do that, but if it has 1M items I would use `List.generate` ctor

Comment: @pskink let's imagine it has 1M items. Why exactly would you use `List.generate`? I can't see any advantages. Info to consider: 1) https://stackoverflow.com/a/61541310/4319264; 2) https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/42283#issuecomment-646167104

Comment: If you have 1M items `list.indexWhere` in the worst case iterates 1M times, and then `list.toList` has to itarate 1M times too

Comment: something like: `List<T> copyListWithReplacement<T>(List<T> list, T replacement, bool Function(T item, T replacement) test) {
return List.generate(list.length, (i) {
return test(list[i], replacement)? replacement : list[i];
});
}`

Comment: I've simplified it a bit:  `List<T> copyListWithReplacement<T>(List<T> list, T Function(T item) test) =>
    List.generate(list.length, (i) => test(list[i]));` It looks better now, but still not ideal. Thanks for the suggestion. @pskink

Comment: and what is "ideal"?

Comment: @pskink something more readable, preferably one that would not involve having to create a function.

Comment: you have somehow to select the item you want to replace so the "test" function is required - the same is for `List.where` / `List.indexWhere` etc

Comment: @pskink Right, but it can be inlined

Comment: what do you mean by "inlined"?

Comment: @pskink I mean I would prefer not to store the function anywhere, but instead use it like inline code. For example, there is `replace()` function in my original question. We can use it's internal code in place we need it. Because the operation is quite simple and it would be overkill to keep the code somewhere and import it. Adds to complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be more elegant to use a comprehension, but it also depends on your desired result. For example, if it is possible for many elements to have the same id and you'd like to replace all of those elements, something like the following could be a solution. (This also returns a new list without side effects to the `list` passed in as an argument.)

```dart
List<BasicDto> replace(BasicDto dto, List<BasicDto> list) =>
    [for (final e in list) e.id == dto.id ? dto : e];
```

Dart has a very nice set of [spread and control flow operators](https://dart.dev/language/collections#spread-operators) that are worth playing around with.

Comment: Nice idea using speread operator, thanks