# How to copy a Rectangle in Dart

Tags: dart

I have two rectangles, one that is occasionally reset to some other rectangle. In C++ I'd just do:

```
_rect = _resetRect;
```

But in Dart that actually means that `_rect` now refers to the same object as `_resetRect` which is not what I want.

My current solution is this:

```
_rect.left = _resetRect.left;
_rect.width = _resetRect.width;
_rect.top = _resetRect.top;
_rect.height = _resetRect.height;
```

This is idiotic. [Other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107906/how-can-i-clone-an-object-deep-copy-in-dart) suggest that there is no built-in way to copy objects (like there is in C++), and you have to rely on the object providing a `clone()` method. But `Rectangle` doesn't have one so what do I do?

Also even if it did have a `clone()` method, wouldn't that allocate an entirely new `Rectangle` rather than just setting the fields of the existing one (like C++'s `operator=`), and therefore be less efficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ also does not have a way to deep-copy an object which contains pointers/references to other objects. In Dart, all values are references, so that restriction applies to all objects.

I assume this is a `MutableRectangle` since the `Rectange` in `dart:math` is unmodifiable.
That class indeed does not have a way to clone the values of another rectangle, so you have to copy each of them. I would use a cascade for that:

```
_rect
  ..left = _resetRect.left
  ..top = _resetRect.top
  ..width = _resetRect.width
  ..height = _resetRect.height;
```

Alternatively, if it happens often enough, you can create a helper function:

```
void copyRectangle(MutableRectangle target, Rectangle source) {
   target
     ..left = source.left
     ..top = source.top
     ..width = source.width
     ..height = source.height;
}
```

Comment: Well that sucks. :-/ By the way (I'm sure you know this but for other people reading), C++ does have a way to deep-copy an object which contains pointers & references - you just have to define custom copy constructors to clone the referenced objects properly.