# How to perform deep copy for a list to another list without affecting the original one in Flutter

Tags: flutter, deep-copy

I have two lists of **Type** object, `_types` and `_filteredTypes`:

```
List<Type> _types = []; // Original list
List<Type> _filteredTypes = []; // Where i bind filter the contents
```

a Type object is:

```
class Type extends Equatable {
  final int id;
  final String title;
  List<SubType>? subTypes;

  Type({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    this.subTypes,
  });
}
```

a SubType object is:

```
class SubType extends Equatable {
  final int id;
  final String title;

  Type({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
  });
}
```

I need to filter the list based on search text, so whenever user types a letter the `_filteredTypes` being updated.

I do the filter on `_onSearchChangedEvent()` within `setState()` like this:

```
_filteredTypes = List.from(_types); // To get the original list without filter

for(var i = 0; i < _filteredTypes.length; i++) {
    // This is where i filter the search result when a subType.title matches the search query:
    _filteredTypes[i].subTypes = List.from(_types[i].subTypes!.where((element) => element.title.toLowerCase().contains(query!.toLowerCase())).toList());
}

// This is where i filter the search result and remove any type doesn't match any subType.title:
_filteredTypes.removeWhere((element) => element.subTypes!.length == 0);

bindTypes(); // To refresh the list widget
```

The problem is when i need get the original list i get the main **type** but **type.subTypes** is still filtered based on the previous search not the original one! even it is copied without reference `_filteredTypes = List.from(_types);`

It seems like a bug in Flutter, any idea guys?

Comment: Can you clarify the question more please? Are you asking why `_types` changes when you change `_filteredTypes` ?

Comment: Yes sure, i need to know why _types.subType changes when _filteredTypes.subType is filtered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to perform a deep copy for a list has sub-list, thanks [moneer alhashim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14314933/moneer-alhashim), your answer guided me.

I'm posting it as an answer to help someone else find the solution easy.

So, the key here is to map the original list `types.map(...)` and fill it manually instead of using `List.from()`, and that will create a new instance for deep objects.

First, i declared one function for each list:

```
//For the parent list:

List<Types> getNewTypesInstance {
    // This function allows to perform a deep copy for the list.
    return types.map((e) =>
        Type(id: e.id, title: e.title, subTypes: e.subTypes))
        .toList();
}


// For the child list:

List<SubType> getNewSubTypesInstance(List<SubType> lst) {
    // This function allows to perform a deep copy for the list:
    return lst.map((e) =>
        SubType(id: e.id, title: e.title))
        .toList();
}
```

And if you have more deep list(s), you will need third function to obtain it as new instance and so on.

Finally, the way how to call them is to write this code within setState():

```
_filteredTypes = getNewTypesInstance

for(var i = 0; i < _filteredTypes.length; i++) {
    // This is where i filter the search result when a subType.title matches the search query:
    _filteredTypes[i].subTypes = List.from(getNewSubTypesInstance(_types[i].subTypes!.where((element) => element.title.toLowerCase().contains(query!.toLowerCase())).toList()));
}

// This is where i filter the search result and remove any type doesn't match any subType.title:
_filteredTypes.removeWhere((element) => element.subTypes!.length == 0);

bindTypes(); // To refresh the list widget
```

Answer (score 1):

`List.from` does not provide you with a deep copy of `_types`- it gives you a shallow copy. Meaning both `_filteredTypes` and `_types` share the same `subTypes`. It's similar in that behavior to this example

```dart
var sharedList = [1];
final listOne = [1, sharedList];
final listTwo = [1, sharedList];
sharedList[0]  = 2;
```

Changing `sharedList` will change the value in both `listOne` and `listTwo`. If shared list was just an integer, changing that integer would not produce the same effect. Like in this example:

```dart
var sharedInteger = 1;
final listOne = [1, sharedInteger];
final listTwo = [1, sharedInteger];
sharedInteger  = 2;
```

When you create an instance of a class may it be built in like `List` or your own custom class, what you get returned is a reference or a pointer to that instance/object. The object itself is allocated on the heap memory area rather than on the stack which means that this object can be referenced outside of functions. As in its life (object life) is not bound by the scope of the function so when you reach the end `}` of the function the object still exists, and its memory is freed by a special program called the garbage collector.

In dart as in many modern programming languages garbage collectors are used and objects are automatically allocated on the heap. In languages such as C++ for example you can allocate objects on the stack, and you have to be explicit about heap allocation, and deallocate any objects on the heap when you are done with them.

All of the above you can look up the gist of it is since `subtypes` is a list, it's a reference type so both `_filteredTypes` and `_types` have that reference. If you want a deep copy you can do that as well, and I'll leave it for you to look that up.

Comment: Thanks for the details, it helps a lot, but i'm wondering how, still can't find a way to perform List deep copy!