# Why does clearing a list clear the first?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I have programmed this little example so that you understand my problem. I make a copy of a list and I am eliminating values from the copy but they are also eliminated from the original. Why does this happen?

The error is: Uncaught Error: Concurrent modification during iteration: Instance of 'JSArray'.

```
void main() 
{
  List<String> list1 = ['jose', 'maria', 'eduardo','emiliano','paula'];
  List<String> list2 = [];
  
  
  list2 = list1;
  for(var name in list1)
  {
    String nameAux = name;
    print(nameAux);
    list2.removeLast();
  }
}
```

I need the original list not to remove the elements like the copy

Thanks

Comment: No, you are not making a copy of your list, because `list2 = list1` just creates an additional reference to the very same list. If you want them independent, you have to clone the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things here:

First, the following only copies the reference to the list, not the list itself

```
list2 = list1;
```

instead, you can use this

```
List<String> list2 = List.from(list1);
```

More details in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58389591/how-to-copy-list-values-to-another-list-in-flutter)

Then, you have another error, you cannot remove items from a list while iterating that list

```
  for(var name in list1)
  {
    list2.removeLast();
  }
```

If you really need to do that, then use this instead, but be careful when you remove an item the next items will hift:

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.gamesList.length; i++)
```

Comment: Please don't answer to questions that have been asked and answered multiple times already, but mark it as a duplicate... Especially don't create answers referring to other posts

Comment: The title says otherwise, and the question also. The exception is a direct result of not cloning the list but just creating an additional reference... Because if you look at the code, op is iterating `list1` but removing from `list2` which wouldn't be a problem, if both lists were different objects and not references to the same list

Comment: This is the error message he listed in his question "The error is: Uncaught Error: Concurrent modification during iteration". Anyway, thanks for your comment, I will definitely use your idea with future posts. Appreciated ;0)

Comment: Yes, and as I explained in the comment, this is a direct result of not cloning the list.

Comment: And yes, you might be new and not be able to cast closing votes yet, but that doesn't mean you should violate community rules