# Flutter list getting sync between screens

Tags: android, ios, flutter, list, dart

I have a list on Screen A
I Navigate to Screen B passing list on Screen A and modify few fields in the list in Screen B

And I press back.
Then the Screen A list is also getting updated.

I need to prevent updating Screen A list unless I manually update the list in Screen A

I am using Navigator to navigate to Scree A

Navigator.push used to pass the Screen A list to Screen B

I modify Screen B list and click on back
Screen A list should not update.

```
class PayeeList {
  List<PayeeData>? data;
}


class PayeeData {
  int? id;
  PayeeAttributes? attributes;
}


class PayeeAttributes {
  num? amount;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;
  User? user;
}
```

Initial list as follow with some data

```
 List<PayeeData>? data = [];




List<PayeeData> payees=  data.toList();
var result = await Navigator.push(context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MultiBlocProvider(
         providers: [
              //REMOVED for sharing in stack overflow
         ],
         child: ExpensePayeesScreen(
             title: "Payees",
             isEdit: false,
             paidAmounts:payees,
              totalAmount: 100))),
          );
```

When I return from screen B the **data** list getting updated

-----------SOLVED-----------

I solved issue by creating the passing temp array as below

```
List<PayeeData> temp = [];
expenseData.attributes?.payees?.data?.forEach((element) {
      PayeeAttributes payeeAttributes = PayeeAttributes(amount: element.attributes?.amount ?? 0, user: element.attributes?.user ?? User());
      temp.add(PayeeData(id: element.id, attributes: payeeAttributes));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `toList` when passing the list to navigator

This will create a new list with the same elements, which means updating the parent list won't update the newly created one.

```dart
void main() {
  final a = [1,2,3];
  final b = a;
  
  a.add(4);
  print('a: $a');         // a: [1, 2, 3, 4]
  print('b: $b');         // b: [1, 2, 3, 4]
  
  final c = a.toList();

  a.add(5);
  print('a: $a');         // a: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  print('c: $c');         // c: [1, 2, 3, 4]
}
```

You can also see other methods to create a new list in that manner here: [How to copy list values to another list in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58389591/how-to-copy-list-values-to-another-list-in-flutter)

There's also an explanation of why that happens in an answer in that question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58389737/10210069

Comment: I tried copyWith also and the suggestion you mentioned. Still the Screen A list getting updated. The above example might work if in same screen. But in my case I pass the list from Screen A to Screen B using Navigator. Then I modify the list in Screen B and come back. (I **don't** pass the modified the list back to Screen A). The Screen A list gets updated.

Comment: could you post a reproducible sample e.g. in dartpad.dev or at least add some code to the question?

Comment: added some code snippet for your reference.

Comment: are you sure you're not changing the list anywhere else or loading it from a bloc once you come back from the other screen?

Comment: I am not changing the list anywhere in the 1st Screen. and the bloc only triggers when the 1st screen loading. I added few logs and tested its not being called when i come back from screen 2

Comment: List<PayeeData> payees=  ( expenseData.attributes?.payees?.data ?? []).toList(); the payees list is sub list of the expenseData object. Can it be a problem?

Comment: I solved issue by creating the passing array as below
List<PayeeData> temp = [];
expenseData.attributes?.payees?.data?.forEach((element) {
      PayeeAttributes payeeAttributes = PayeeAttributes(amount: element.attributes?.amount ?? 0, user: element.attributes?.user ?? User());
      temp.add(PayeeData(id: element.id, attributes: payeeAttributes));
});

Comment: Ah, I think I get it now - you must have modified a nested list and copied the outer list. What you did right there is copy the inner one - it's the same principle as described in my answer

Comment: Yes the same principle as you explained. Some additional workaround. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new list from reference from previous list,

```
List<String> listA = ["apple", "banana", "cat"];
```

Instead of directly assigning list like:

```
List<String> listB = listA;
```

You can do,

```
List<String> listB = List.from(listA);
```

This will create a completely new list from data of listA and modifying listB will not affect listA.

Comment: If the list is complex object list the object reference won't get copied. I resolved issue by creating new instance of the objects and assigning to new list.