# Understanding = operator in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, hybrid-mobile-app

What does `=` do here?

```
List<Segment> totalSegments = flight.departureFlight.segments;
```

Do both, `totalSegments` and `flight.departureFlight.segments` point to the same memory reference or `totalSegments` has the same data as `flight.departureFlight.segments` but points to a different memory location?
My understanding was that the latter should happen since dart is pass by value and not reference. However, a very annoying bug occurred when I added this line below that one:

```
totalSegments.addAll(flight.returnFlight.segments);
```

This above line actually modified the `flight` variable which in turn somehow modified the `AsyncSnapshot` from the `StreamBuilder`. Although, I wasn't using the variable anywhere else and not modifying other variables mentioned.
This all happened inside `build` function of a Stateless Widget. Maybe that has to do something with it.
I tried reading [dart documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour) for it, but either I couldn't find what I am looking for or the information is simply missing there. Read [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dart_programming/dart_programming_operators.htm) too, but according to this, my use case shouldn't happen.

Comment: have you declared ``List<Segment> totalSegments = flight.departureFlight.segments;`` statement in the build() method? IF yes, it will cause change in totalSegments if you update ``flight.departureFlight.segments;`` since build method is recalled on ``setState``

Comment: My issue is actually the other way round. Changing `totalSegments` causes change in the actual `flight` object and at other places too.

Comment: how's that even possible? Check if you've anywhere manipulated the actual ``flight``

Comment: I did not. I think when I am using = operator. It's just assigning the same reference to `totalSegment` as of `flight.departureFlight.segments` and hence the trouble. I don't know if it should behave like this or not is the question.

Comment: no, it doesn't work like that. Making a change in ``flight.departureFlight.segments;`` can update ``totalSegments`` but not vice-versa.

Comment: It **is** working like that. That's why the question. You can try it too, otherwise I'll create a sample project on github to re-create the issue.

Comment: sure, please create a minimal code to represent your issue. I want to test.

Comment: also, you didn't answer where you have declared ``List<Segment> totalSegments = flight.departureFlight.segments;``

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to objects as in your case, you are assigning a reference to an existing object (memory location) to a new variable. While acting upon that reference, you change the same object.

If this is not what you intend, check out [answers related to (deep) copying of the objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107906/how-can-i-clone-an-object-deep-copy-in-dart)

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Segment> totalSegments = flight.departureFlight.segments;
```

This expression does the following.

Assigns the value of the expression `flight.departureFlight.segments` to variable `totalSegments`.

This and only this and nothing more.
There is no need to know what is really happening, because this is what happens.

P.S.
What value will be obtained as a result of executing the expression `flight.departureFlight.segments` is another question, because it depends on the implementation of the members of the operands of the expression `flight.departureFlight.segments`.

Answer (score 0):

You were mistaken by the fact that Dart passes by value, and not by reference. Actually, it is exactly the opposite: (Almost) everything is always passed by reference (Which is usually a good thing!) Therefore, it is quite logical that because you edited `totalSegments` your `departureflight.segments` got edited too. It is a synonym. One of the ways to solve your problem would be:

```
List<Segment> totalSegments = List();
totalSegments.addAll(flight.departureFlight.segments.toList());
```