# How to make copy of array's elements in the dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Getting wired issue like main array has been changed if changed value of another array. I think issue is about copying same address, not sure but just thinking of it. I have tried from last 3 hours but unable to get rid from it.

Look at below illustration to get better idea.

```
List<page> _pageList;
List<page> _orderList = [];
_pageList = _apiResponse.result as List<page>;
_orderList.add(_pageList[0].element);
_orderList[0].title = "XYZ" 
//--> Here if I change the `_orderList[0].title` then it also change the `title` inside "_pageList"
```

How can we prevent the changes in main array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got same issue in my one of the project. What I have done is, use `json` to encode and decode object that help you to make copy of the object so that will not be affected to the main List.

After 3rd line of your code, make changes like below

```
Elements copyObject = Elements.fromJson(_pageList[0].element.toJson());
// First of all you have to convert your object to the Map and and map to original object like above
_orderList.add(copyObject);
```

Hope that will help you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a getter function to create a copy of your list and use that instead of
altering your actual list.
example:

```
List<Page> get orderList{
return [..._orderList];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lists in Dart store references for complex types, so this is intended behaviour.

From your code:

> `_orderList.add(_pageList[0].element);`

`_orderList[0]` and `_pageList[0].element` point to the same reference (if they are non-primitive).

There is no general `copy()` or `clone()` method in dart, as far as i know. So you need to copy the object yourself, if you want a separate instance. (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107906/how-can-i-clone-an-object-deep-copy-in-dart))