# Flutter: clone class without reference

Tags: flutter

I can clone Maps like this:

```
var copy = json.decode(json.encode(original));
```

but how could I do similar thing for classes without converting it to a Map?

```
var original = new Original();

var copy = original;

copy.prop = "New";

print(original.prop); // this should be "old", not "new"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I clone an Object (deep copy) in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107906/how-can-i-clone-an-object-deep-copy-in-dart)

Comment: I do not understand what's the problem with using maps. If it is such a big problem, why don't you make a function in the class called clone where u creat a new Object of that class and loop over all the properties assigning them

Comment: https://developer.school/dart-flutter-what-does-copywith-do

Comment: https://www.flutterclutter.dev/flutter/basics/clone-copy-objects-in-dart/2020/1851/

Comment: @TechnicalWorld you are creating another reference

Comment: what I never did was converting it back from Map to class

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct method do this with a class. I have to create the class again like this:

```
var copy = new Original(prop: "new");

print(original.prop); // "old"
print(copy.prop); // "new"
```