# How to Copy an Object without Create Reference Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, object, reference

I want to give object value from another but when I modify name2 it modify name1 at same time.

```
Item item2 = item1;
item2.name = 'a';
```

I want every object not linked to each other.

Comment: can you include the model class?

Comment: considered it any class with any properties just make it when you equal the class with new class when you change property value not changing in the parent class property value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have an item class with the properties `id` and `name`. You can copy a class without referencing it if you create a `copyWith` method like below. It will copy the class and modify only the values that you pass as arguments. Try it out in [Dart Pad](https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true).

```
void main() {
  final Item item1 = Item(id: 1, name: 'Item 1');
  final Item item2 = item1.copyWith(name: 'Item 2');
  print(item1); // Item{id: 1, name: Item 1}
  print(item2); // Item{id: 1, name: Item 2}
  print(item1); // Item{id: 1, name: Item 1}
}

class Item {
  const Item({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
  });
  final int id;
  final String name;

  Item copyWith({int? id, String? name}) => Item(
        id: id ?? this.id,
        name: name ?? this.name,
      );
  
  @override
  String toString()=> 'Item{id: $id, name: $name}';
}
```

Comment: Thank you alot, I've been trying before to despair. but is dart has any function or property or way from it self to make it not referencing?

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: Ok, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Considering you are using a Map,
You can use `from` to achieve this, reference answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28554128/9481880)

```
Item Item1 = {
    'foo': 'bar'
};
Item Item2 = new Item.from(Item1);
```

You can also use `fromJson` and `toJson` to achieve this

```
Item1 = Item.fromJson(Item2.toJson());
```

but for this you need to create `fromJson` and `toJson` manually.
you can do that easily by pasting your json [here](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/)

Comment: It's not Json. and there is no 'from' property for object?