# When Modify a Value in the Copied List, It Modify the Value in The Original List Flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dart, copy

I want to copy list and make no reference even when I edit value in copied list. I tried `addAll()`, `List.from()`, `map()`, `toList()` and `[...myList]` but they were unhelpful.

*Edit for Clarification*

Ex:

```
class Item{
    String description;
    int price; 

    Item(this.description, this.price);
    }

List<Item> items = [
Item('item 1', 100),
Item('item 2', 200),
Item('item 3', 300),
];

List<Item> selectedItems = List.from(items);
```

When I edit `selectedItems` original list `items` shouldn't be affected, but it's not?!

```
selectedItems[0].price = 115;
```

it modifies the price of element 0 in both.

Comment: could you please show us some codes that you tried before so your question will be more clearly?

Comment: any list equals to another list, make when you modify copied list (the second list) original list should not modify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flutter haven't copy function for objects, you should create "copy constructor" manually. It's discussed here: [How can I clone an Object (deep copy) in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107906/how-can-i-clone-an-object-deep-copy-in-dart)

Solution for your example:

```
void main() {
  // Original list
  List<Item> items = [
    Item('item 1', 100),
    Item('item 2', 200),
    Item('item 3', 300),
  ];

  // Copied list
  List<Item> selectedItems = items.map((it) => Item.copy(it)).toList();

  // Change price for item in copied list
  selectedItems[0].price = 115;

  print("Original list:");
  items.forEach((it) => print("Description: ${it.description}, price: ${it.price}"));

  print("Copied list:");
  selectedItems.forEach((it) => print("Description: ${it.description}, price: ${it.price}"));
}

class Item {
  String description;
  int price;

  Item(this.description, this.price);

  // Copied constructor
  Item.copy(Item item) : this(item.description, item.price);
}
```

Comment: I am using this already, is there different `Item copyWith() => Item(this.description, this.price);`

Comment: It works with delete some elements inside copied list it does not deletes from original list but when I edit not works?

Comment: ok it works with both ways just I am not using `items.map((it) => Item.copy(it)).toList();` when defining selectedList. Thank you :)