# Flutter/Dart set all fields in object to same object

Tags: flutter, dart

simple question here but wondering if anyone can offer the right solution.
I want to take in an object of the same type as my current class, and set all my fields to that object's fields, without individually setting each out. Is there a way to do that easily or no?

Eg.,

```
  User({required this.uid}) {
    Database().getUser(uid).listen((User user) async {
      displayName = user?.displayName;
      email = user?.email;
      phoneNumber = user?.phoneNumber;
      photoURL = user?.photoURL;
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }
```

The above works but isn't clean.
I want to be able to do the above in 1 line, eg., set

```
this.user = user
```

Not sure if this is possible. Thanks!

Comment: please write expected output in your question,  so we can answer it easily

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/13107906/12257758